# Placement of Condition /; expressions

Tags: coding-style

It is my practice to place `Condition` expressions on the left side of `:=` and `:>` in almost every case.

1. I find this to be more logical as it is part of the pattern

   With the exception of use inside `Module`, `Block`, or `With` on the RHS, which is a special case, the Condition depends only on the LHS, and therefore IMHO is more logically placed on the LHS
2. Its behavior remains consistent when used with `=` and `->`

   - `f[x_] /; x < 5 := 1` and `g[x_] /; x < 5 = 1` behave *similarly*
   - `f[x_] := 1 /; x < 5` and `g[x_] = 1 /; x < 5` behave *differently*
3. The evaluation path is significantly less complicated

   Placing the condition on the RHS requires the internal use of `RuleCondition` and `$ConditionHold` which can significantly slow down simple functions.

   ```
   Clear[f, g]

   f[x_] /; OddQ[x] := 1
   f[x_] := 0;

   g[x_] := 1 /; OddQ[x]
   g[x_] := 0;

   f[4] //Trace
   ```

   > ```
   > {f[4], {OddQ[4], False}, 0}
   > ```

   ```
   g[4] //Trace
   ```

   > ```
   > {g[4],{{OddQ[4],False},RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[1]],False],Fail},0}
   > ```

   ```
   a = Range@1*^6;

   Timing[f /@ a;]
   Timing[g /@ a;]
   ```

   > ```
   > {0.421, Null}
   > {0.655, Null}
   > ```

Nevertheless, the documentation for `Condition` shows the RHS form and many experienced users also seem to favor this form.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Which form should be standard, and why?

---

A brief edit:  The form `f[x_ /; x < 5] := 1` is what I use most often as should be clear to those who read my answers on StackOverflow.  I omitted this form specifically because I didn't want to spawn a discussion (bad for SE sites) about purely-stylistic differences.  I see now that this may have had the opposite effect.  Rather I wish to focus this question on the apparently canonical yet IMHO inferior RHS placement and what its merits are.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I prefer the Condition to appear on the left-hand-side and outside the square brackets for several reasons.

**Type signature**

I often think of the condition as (part of) the analog of the [signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) in a typed language, so it should go on the left hand side.

**Order of operations**

I like that the elements of the function definition appear in the order in which I want them to happen:

```
f[x_] /; x > 0 := Sqrt[x]
```

1. Look for f[x_].
2. Check that x > 0.
3. Return Sqrt[x].
4. (Optional) Check any postcondition (see below).

**Function contract**

When an argument-checking definition of the form

```
f[else___] := Throw["Error in f."]
```

appears, a left-hand-side Condition often plays the role of a [precondition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition) in the sense of [Design By Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). A Condition can also appear on the right-hand-side and this plays the role of a [postcondition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondition):

```
f[x_] /; x > 0 := Sqrt[x] /; Sqrt[x] > 0
```

**Consistency of appearance**

I prefer `f[x_] /; x > 0` to the alternative `f[x_ /; x > 0]` for consistency, because sometimes placing the Condition inside the square brackets is not possible, such as when the Condition depends on multiple arguments:

```
f[x_, y_] /; x > y := 1/(x - y)
```

**Update: Rationale**

I think [Brett's preference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/579/31) of putting the Condition as close as possible to the quantity to which it applies is equally good so I want to explain why I ended up with my slightly different preference.

Basically I was writing a sequence of definitions like this, following Brett's guideline:

```
f[x_ /; c1[x], y_] := this
f[x_, y_ /; c2[y]] := that
f[x_, y_] /; c3[x, y] := other
```

Note that all of these define f[x, y]. So there are two things I didn't like about that:

1. The key difference between each LHS is the different conditions on x and y, and these are difficult to read quickly here because they all start at different places and are mixed in with f[x_, y_].
2. When a condition needs to change such that it suddenly starts or stops depending on x or y, I need to move it from inside the square brackets to outside or vice versa.

Now compare:

```
f[x_, y_] /; c1[x] := this
f[x_, y_] /; c2[y] := that
f[x_, y_] /; c3[x, y] := other
```

Of course, what would make even more sense would be to adhere to Brett's guideline except in special cases like above! Maybe I will try that now ...

Comment: +1 Since you work at Wolfram Research, do you have any thought about why only the RHS form is shown in the documentation of Condition?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In the documentation for [Condition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html), the very first case "patt /; test" is actually the LHS form of Condition. For example patt could be x_ or f[x_]. The other two are the RHS form.

Comment: Very nice write up. Personally I keep the practice of keeping conditions on a single variable next to it, simply because I like to think of it as a type or interface. So some functions read h[x_List] and others will read h[x_/;x>4]. But of cause there are cases of mixed patterns as you note, which must be moved outside.

Answer (score 21):

Another reason to use the LHS placement is mentioned in passing by Robby Villegas in the devcon99 presentation [Working with Unevaluated Expressions](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions.nb):

> I recommend that you hang the condition /; ... off the lhs, not the rhs, because then you can revoke the definition by plopping the whole lhs into an Unset command

For example:

```
f[x_] /; foo := 2 x  (* imagine a long definition *)
f[x_] /; bar := 5 x
```

We can clear one of the definitions using only the LHS:

```
Unset[f[x_] /; foo]

Definition[f]
```

> ```
> f[x_] /; bar := 5 x
> ```

If using the RHS placement this Unset does not work:

```
g[x_] := 2 x /; foo
g[x_] := 5 x /; bar

Unset[g[x_] /; foo]
```

> During evaluation of In[3]:= Unset::norep: Assignment on g for g[x_]/;foo not found. >>
>
> ```
> $Failed
> ```

Answer (score 20):

My general preference is to put the condition as close as possible to the quantity to which it applies:

... to a single argument:

```
f[x_ /; x > 2, y_] := x + y

{f[1, 2], f[3, 2]}
```

> ```
> {f[1, 2], 5}
> ```

... to a relationship between arguments:

```
g[x_, y_] /; x > y := x + y

{g[1, 2], g[3, 2]}
```

> ```
> {g[1, 2], 5}
> ```

... to a value calculated during the evaluation of the function:

```
h[x_, y_] := Module[{z = x + y}, z^2 /; z > 3]

{h[1, 2], h[3, 2]}
```

> ```
> {h[1, 2], 25}
> ```

Comment: I think this is a very sensible policy though my answer proposed a different one.

Answer (score 14):

Style is a matter of taste and education. There is not a definite answer, only a personal answer. Having said that, there is another way for the condition that is common in code:

```
h[x_ /; OddQ[x]] := 1;
h[x_] := 0
h[4] // Trace
```

My personal preference is your `f[]` style, since I find that a good compromise between readability and closeness to the actual symbol involved. Imagine a long `Module`, then you'd have to scroll quite a bit to get/find the condition. The benefit of the RHS method is readability for people.

Comment: This is actually the form I prefer.

Comment: I use this form as well, preferring to keep conditions close to the pattern they apply to, but I was trying to not complicate things in my question.

Comment: I have updated the question with a small note attempting to focus the topic on the RHS placement.

Answer (score 10):

My preference is the same as [Andrew's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/541/34), for the consistency and layout reasons he specified. That is, put the precondition `Condition` after the function's pattern, `f[x_, y_] /; test[x,y] := ...` - even if `test` only depends on a single variable/blank.

But I'd like to add an extra reason for not putting the `Condition` inside the function brackets, which is anytime you can do that, you could use a `PatternTest` (`?`) instead. That is, instead of

```
f[x_/;test[x], y] := ...
```

you could and maybe should use

```
f[x_?test, y] := ...
```

---

As for putting the condition on the LHS of the rule/definition vs the RHS, I once again agree with Andrew and with Mr.Wizard's comments in the question.

Comment: I favor `x_ /; x<5` over `x_?(#<5&)` for clarity.  If using a named test function I agree that PatternTest will be cleaner.