# Subtle difference in conditional rules placement

Tags: evaluation

I had gotten used to thinking of the placement of a condition in a rule definition as logically immaterial. In my specific example, namely

```
ClearAll[f,g,h];
SetAttributes[f,HoldAllComplete];
f[x_ /; Head@Unevaluated@x === Symbol] := x;

SetAttributes[g,HoldAllComplete];
g[x_] := x /; Head@Unevaluated@x === Symbol;

SetAttributes[h,HoldAllComplete];
h[x_] /; Head@Unevaluated@x === Symbol := x;
```

all three produce the same results when applied to the same symbol

```
In[13]:= f[foo] === g[foo] === h[foo] === foo

(* Out[13]= True *)
```

But now I try to get fancy and write the following

```
ClearAll[f, g, h, foo];
SetAttributes[f,HoldAllComplete];
f[x_ /; Head@Unevaluated@x === Symbol] := Unevaluated@x;

SetAttributes[g,HoldAllComplete]
g[x_] := Unevaluated@x /; Head@Unevaluated@x === Symbol;

SetAttributes[h,HoldAllComplete]
h[x_] /; Head@Unevaluated@x === Symbol := Unevaluated@x;

In[20]:= {f[foo], g[foo], h[foo]}
```

and the results are very different

```
(* Out[20]= {foo, Unevaluated[foo], foo} *)
```

I try to figure it out with [traceView2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459735/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence); I can see the differences

[image: traceView2 differences]

but I get quickly lost in the documents trying to understand what, why, and how.  Seems even this example is not so simple and probes dark (at least to me) corners of the evaluator.  I'd be grateful for advice, explanations, ideas.

Comment: Related (possibly, even a dupe): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/533/5

Comment: @R.M Not really a dupe -- this has more to do with the behavior of `Unevaluated` itself.  Working on an answer now.

Comment: I love that traceview2 & 4 function. It is a lifesaver. I would +1 for the reference alone.

Comment: A relevant discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267143/why-doesnt-ruledelayed-hold-unevaluated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't a runtime issue, so you won't find the answer by tracing `f[foo]` and family.

It's a definition thing. If you look at the downvalues you'll see that in `f` as well as in `h` the `Unevaluated` got stripped off when running the `SetDelayed`

Let's look at the fullform of your definitions

f:

```
SetDelayed[
 f[Condition[Pattern[x, Blank[]], 
   SameQ[Head[Unevaluated[x]], Symbol]]],
 Unevaluated[x]]
```

So, Mathematica sees this code. 
First it evaluates `SetDelayed`, it is inert.

It checks its attributes: `HoldAll`, `SequenceHold`.

Now it strips off the `Unevaluated` of its arguments... (!!)

Evaluates the expression as a whole, and stores the definition (the `Unevaluated` is gone already)

g:

```
SetDelayed[
 g[Pattern[x, Blank[]]],
 Condition[Unevaluated[x], SameQ[Head[Unevaluated[x]], Symbol]]]
```

Now, in this case, no argument has head `Unevaluated` so it survives :)

h:

```
SetDelayed[
 Condition[h[Pattern[x, Blank[]]], 
  SameQ[Head[Unevaluated[x]], Symbol]], Unevaluated[x]]
```

Same as `f`, goodbye `Unevaluated`

Comment: I see you had a quite different analysis, and it appears to be the correct one.

Comment: Interestingly, I think my observation is still valid, even if it does not directly apply here.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. My answer is probably even confusing to someone that takes it as more general than it is intended... Yours shows the true spirit of Unevaluated

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the sentence "Strips `Evaluate`, evaluates the arguments with it". Which `Evaluate`?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries that was just a short attempt to be less particular. Makes no sense in this case because there's nothing to strip. I'm deleting it

Comment: The only part of this I didn't understand was "Strips `Evaluate`, evaluates the arguments with it."  I don't see an `Evaluate` to strip -- is it inserted implicitly?  Thank you both for your great answers.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin, I deleted it because you're the second person who tells me it was confusing. I was struggling between being more general in the evaluation process and being particular and to the point. There is no `Evaluate` in here. Just like there is no point is saying that it first evaluates the head when it is inert. Perhaps I should delete that too

Comment: No, it's valuable to say that it first evaluates the head to inert, since the head is actually there and it reminds us that MMA actually does evaluate the heads, unlike some languages where the evaluation of the head is done completely at compile time and the compiler substitutes essentially a constant in the head positions.

Comment: btw, Rojo, I'm curious how you got the FullForms since something like `(f[x_ /; Head@Unevaluated@x === Symbol] := x) // FullForm` just produces `Null`.  A captive function, like the one I'm working on in this other question (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3216/impossible-to-bypass-evaluation-on-returned-values) produces the slightly more valuable result `{SetDelayed, {f, {Condition, {Pattern, 
    x, {Blank}}, {SameQ, {Head, {Unevaluated, x}}, Symbol}}}, x}`

Comment: `FullForm` doesn't evaluate, it's just formatting... But it evaluates its arguments if necessary. You can prevent this by wrapping a `HoldForm` for example... Try `(f[x_ /; Head@Unevaluated@x === Symbol] := x) // FullForm // HoldForm`

Comment: While the main observation you made is almost correct, and you get a +1 for it, I must mention that the main culprit is not `SetDelayed` but `RuleDelayed`, and so, it *is* a run-time thing. You may find [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267143/why-doesnt-ruledelayed-hold-unevaluated) interesting.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, let's see, reading

Comment: @Rojo In fact, sorry for not having looked more carefully, you are probably correct for this particular case. The first level of `Unevaluated` seems to indeed be stripped by `SetDelayed`. But, your explanation alone won't explain e.g. this: `ClearAll[f];SetAttributes[f, HoldAllComplete];
f[x_] := Unevaluated@Unevaluated[x]; DownValues[f]`. By doing this: `Block[{RuleDelayed = HoldComplete}, Hold[Evaluate[DownValues[f]]]]`, you can see that all other layers of `Unevaluated` are stripped at run-time by `RuleDelayed`.

Comment: @Rojo Oh boy... it's like 4 a.m. here, and this topic is not one for a 5 minutes talk. Let's postpone a bit, if you don't mind.

Comment: Sure. Anyway, that special behaviour of `RuleDelayed` is interesting and I didn't know it, thanks. But I don't yet see how it could affect evaluation (in cases where you don't use `DownValues` or `RuleDelayed` explicitly). Got a simple example?

Comment: here is a git gist that produces pretty displays of Rojo's full forms -- https://gist.github.com/2128704

Answer (score 5):

This highlights a subtle difference in `Condition` expressions but at its heart I believe is the behavior of `Unevaluated`, not `Condition`.

Consider first:

```
List[Unevaluated[1 + 1], "foo"]

Plus[Unevaluated[1 + 1], "foo"]
```

> ```
> {Unevaluated[1 + 1], "foo"}
>
> 2 + "foo"
> ```

`Unevaluated` is only stripped when *Mathematica* determines that further evaluation is necessary (or perhaps conversely, it remains when *Mathematica* does not evaluate).  Consider now:

```
List[#, "foo"] & @ Unevaluated[1 + 1]
```

> ```
> {2, "foo"}
> ```

Because the pure function is not `HoldAllComplete` an additional evaluation is triggered that does not occur when using `List` directly.

You can strip down your question example to this observation:

```
ff := Unevaluated[1 + 1]

gg := Unevaluated[1 + 1] /; True

{ff, gg}
```

> ```
> {2, Unevaluated[1 + 1]}
> ```

Apparently the use of `Condition` causes *Mathematica* to consider that the RHS expression has already been evaluated.

Comment: Nice find. That `Unevaluated` stays is not consistent with "tutorial/Evaluation" which says "Unless h has attribute HoldAllComplete, strip the outermost of any Unevaluated wrappers that appear in the Subscript[e, i]." but does not mention that this only happens when further evaluation is possible.