# Impossible to bypass evaluation on returned values?

Tags: evaluation

Following all the great advice on [this other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2749/how-to-really-hold-arguments-and-capture-fullform), I'm now fluent with `HoldAllComplete` and `Unevaluated` on the **input** side of quote-type functions.  I continued my investigations and produced the following attempt at a generic conversion from expression to captive (or quoted) expression:

```
ClearAll[captive];
SetAttributes[captive, HoldAllComplete];
captive[expr_ /; AtomQ @ Unevaluated @ expr] := expr
captive[head_[args___]] := 
    {captive @ head} ~Join~ (captive /@ (Unevaluated @ {args}))
captive[x___] := Throw[{x}];
```

This is really great and handles **almost** all my scenarios.  To wit, the following abbreviated test set produces the desired results

```
testSet = {"foo", foo, 12, 0, 3/4, 3.14, 2.72 + 3.14 I, 
  Infinity, {1, 2, 3}, {1, "a", b}, f, f[b], f[1, "a", b], f[{}], 
  f[{1, "a", b}], f[a][b], f[a][1, "a", b], f[a][{}], 
  f[a][{1, "a", b}], Hold[Plus @@ {}], Hold[Plus @@ {1, 2, 3}], 
  Plus @@ {1, "a", b}, 1 + "a" b, a + b*c};
```

as we can see in the output of

```
MapThread[List, {
  InputForm /@ testSet, 
  InputForm /@ captive /@ testSet}] // TraditionalForm
```

(input on left, output on right)

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{foo} & \text{foo} \\
 \text{foo} & \text{foo} \\
 12 & 12 \\
 0 & 0 \\
 3/4 & 3/4 \\
 3.14 & 3.14 \\
 2.72 + 3.14*I & 2.72 + 3.14*I \\
 \text{Infinity} & \{\text{DirectedInfinity}, 1\} \\
 \{1, 2, 3\} & \{\text{List}, 1, 2, 3\} \\
 \{1, \text{a}, b\} & \{\text{List}, 1, \text{a}, b\} \\
 f & f \\
 f[b] & \{f, b\} \\
 f[1, \text{a}, b] & \{f, 1, \text{a}, b\} \\
 f[\{\}] & \{f, \{\text{List}\}\} \\
 f[\{1, \text{a}, b\}] & \{f, \{\text{List}, 1, \text{a}, b\}\} \\
 f[a][b] & \{\{f, a\}, b\} \\
 f[a][1, \text{a}, b] & \{\{f, a\}, 1, \text{a}, b\} \\
 f[a][\{\}] & \{\{f, a\}, \{\text{List}\}\} \\
 f[a][\{1, \text{a}, b\}] & \{\{f, a\}, \{\text{List}, 1, \text{a}, b\}\} \\
 \text{Hold}[\text{Plus} \text{@@} \{\}] & \{\text{Hold}, \{\text{Apply}, \text{Plus}, \{\text{List}\}\}\} \\
 \text{Hold}[\text{Plus} \text{@@} \{1, 2, 3\}] & \{\text{Hold}, \{\text{Apply}, \text{Plus}, \{\text{List}, 1, 2, 3\}\}\} \\
 1 + \text{a} + b & \{\text{Plus}, 1, \text{a}, b\} \\
 1 + \text{a}*b & \{\text{Plus}, 1, \{\text{Times}, \text{a}, b\}\} \\
 a + b*c & \{\text{Plus}, a, \{\text{Times}, b, c\}\} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

I get into trouble, however, when a **return value** of a captive expression has a value. For instance, something as simple as

```
x = y
(* Out[10]= y *)
captive[x]
(* Out[11]= y *)
```

[traceView2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459735/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence) reveals that captive inspects the Held input, as required, but that the evaluator apparently snatches it on the way out, and we don't get `x`, the desired result.

[image: captive fail]

In hindsight, I suppose I shouldn't expect more, since the ever-present term-rewriter (evaluator) is just the way MMA is supposed to work.  On a guess, I tried

```
captive[expr_ /; AtomQ @ Unevaluated @ expr] := Unevaluated @ expr
```

which doesn't seem to make any difference (and, after reading the docs, I'm not surprised, since `Unevaluated` only seems to have an effect when supplied in a function-argument slot (see [this other question in progress](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3209/subtle-difference-in-conditional-rules-placement) related to behavior of Unevaluated).

I could do

```
captive[expr_ /; AtomQ @ Unevaluated @ expr] := Hold @ expr
```

or, better,

```
captive[expr_ /; AtomQ @ Unevaluated @ expr] := If[ValueQ @ expr, Hold @ expr,expr]
```

but now my output will always have `Hold` wrapping symbols that have values.  I am beginning to suspect **that this may be the best I can do**, and I'm prepared to accept that answer (it means that my other function, which frees the captive, will have to have to release the particular holds inserted by this process (and not the Holds that were in the original source expressions!?! which means I probably have to mark them specially, but that's for another topic!)

But before giving up, I thought I'd consult you all, who have already been so generous.

Comment: please tell me you did not write that latex array by hand...

Comment: "Copy as LaTeX" on right click in MMA -- too easy!

Comment: I think you almost certainly want something like `HoldForm` or `Defer`.

Comment: helpful Grid-form displays for captive expressions:  https://gist.github.com/2128704

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it seems that you just hit the fundamental problem of this approach: *any* global definition is attached to some symbol. In cases of `DownValues`, `SubValues` and perhaps `UpValues`, this does not harm your approach. But for `OwnValues` (meaning symbols which have direct values, i.e. variables), it does. You pretty much made this observation yourself. You have to decide which semantics you wish for your function. From what I can tell, you probably *do* wish to wrap them in some `Hold`-like wrapper.

However, I would take a different road. I would use `Block` dynamically, to make a dynamic environment where these symbols are `Block`-ed, and work in that dynamic environment for whatever code transformations (quoting, etc) you may wish to perform. Yet another approach is to temporarily hide certain symbols with some dummy symbols (assuming that your goal is to make some portions of your code inert and available as data) - I described a very simple version of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741671/unevaluated-form-of-ai/8746584#8746584). I actually did write a quoting library based on a combination of these two approaches, for some code-generation purposes, and this worked out quite well for me.

Comment: I came up with this as a step along the journey -- `captive[expr_ /; AtomQ @ Unevaluated @ expr] := If[ValueQ @ expr, captive @ Evaluate @ expr, expr]`

Comment: Btw, apologies for a meta comment, I have a really nice Grid function for displaying the "S-Expressions" resulting from this "captive" that I'd like to share.  Maybe I should put it up in a github repo?  Too big for a comment and not appropriate for an "answer" here, unless you advise otherwise.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin To see whether or not this solves your problem I would have to know more about what your problem is. I suspect that this is not a good thing, if your goals are to make some quoting mechanism - because then you probably should operate on code as it stands, and prevent *all* evaluation - while your first branch of `If` attempts to evaluate something (an attempt that would in fact fail, because `Evaluate` is not strong enough to handle `HoldAllComplete` heads).

Comment: forgot to say above  -- and MUST change the Attributes from `HoldAllComplete` to `HoldAll`.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin You can e.g. use GitHub gists, which give an easy way to share smaller projects / code fragments/ files. You can make a gist with this, and then link to it from your question, as an additional remark. At least, that's probably what I would do. You can have more than one file in a gist.

Comment: My goals are similar to yours -- code generation.  The above was just to get around some `Throws` I inserted in some instrumentation displays.  The displays will now clearly show the cases where symbols are being evaluated.  My next attack will take your `Block` suggestion and see what I can do with it.  In parallel, I will stay unblocked on the code-gen side by just restricting my use cases to those wherein symbols don't have values.  That way, I can pursue code-gen and quoting in parallel.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Sounds like a good plan, good luck with it and keep us posted :)

Comment: Leonid -- brilliant.  Thanks.  https://gist.github.com/2128704

Comment: @Reb.Cabin That's great. I have to leave now, so will look at it tomorrow. Why don't you place a link somewhere inside your question's text? This way people will be able to see it (not everyone reads comments).

Comment: I have a much better solution, now, at this gist https://gist.github.com/2313720 .  Basically it turns everything into strings and tags them with symbolic heads that can be pattern-matched in applications!

Comment: @Reb.Cabin I will surely have a look at that as well, thanks for the link. I am a bit worried about conversion to strings though: for a number of reasons, this is often not a good option in Mathematica. My experience tells me that it is best to stay within the parsed code, and not involve the parser, and transitions to strings and back,  if at all possible.

Comment: Leonid (i can't type at-signs -- something removes them!)  Roger about strings.  Will investigate.  Perhaps the only good thing about the approach is that it isolates the pain in one place (parsing / unparsing) and doesn't involve the evaluator.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin They are removed when there are just two people commenting, and comments are below the answer by one of them - the sysem assumes that in this case there is no ambiguity as to whom the comment is addressed (which makes sense), and the author of the answer is notified in any case. I am off for today, but hope to get some time over the weekend to look at all this stuff.