# How can I use nested conditionals inside my functions?

Tags: programming, pattern-matching

I'm a big fan of using conditionals inside my functions to deal with cases, that is, to pattern match in stages and possibly leave a function unevaluated.

```
In[1]:= f[x_] :=
 (
   (
     (
       True
       ) /; EvenQ[x]
     ) /; x > 2
   ) /; x < 10

In[2]:= f[4]
Out[2]= True
```

However I don't fully understand the extent to which I can do this. For example, mixing If statements in doesn't work:

```
In[3]:= 
    h[x_] :=
     (
       If[x > 2,
        (
          True
          ) /; EvenQ[x]
        ,
        False
        ]
       ) /; x < 10

    In[4]:= h[4]
    Out[4]= True /; EvenQ[4]
```

A clarification on both the limitation and merits of this style of coding would be helpful.

I find this style of programming to be handy for a number of reasons, but a primary reason is the ease of defining a blanket default case and letting the pattern matching do its work, e.g. `f[_] := $Failed`.

Comment: The reason the second breaks is because something like (5/;True) doesn't evaluate to 5 (such as If[] would have). The outermost pattern is used to check when the function definition applies, but the innermost is just a returned pattern. As for the first function, I would personally prefer to write it as  f[x_ /; (EvenQ[x] && 2 < x < 10)] := True.

Comment: A related stylistic question is [Placement of Condition /; expressions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/533/245)

Comment: Conditions are really always parts of patterns and replacement rules, and in isolation they are just symbolic expressions with no semantics. Once you mix patterns and non-pattern code (`If`-s etc), you are likely to generate such situations. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866016/question-on-condition) for a relevant discussion.

Comment: Regarding your update, you can also get `f[_] := $Failed` behavior using `And`; also, you still have not described the output you desire from `h`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the general notion here is that conditional patterns `x_/;EvenQ[x]` and conditional expressions `If[EvenQ[x],a,b]` are not the same thing. In your first example, you nest conditional patterns in the definition of f which means that all the conditions have to be true for a match against the pattern to be successful. In the second, only the outermost condition is actually used in the definition of h, and it assumes you want your returned expression from the True case of `If[x>2,...]` to return a conditional pattern when `x>2`. which is what you get, the conditional pattern `True /; EvenQ[4]`. This pattern matches against True, so `MatchQ[True, True /; EvenQ[4]]` would return `True`.

If I understand your intention correctly the second function would be defined as:

```
 h[x_ /; (EvenQ[x] && x < 10)] := If[x > 2, True, False]
```

Note that I have kept all the conditional patterns on the left, and return a conditional expression, which evaluates depending on x.

Comment: +1 for fast response and making `h` more like `f`.

Answer (score 4):

It's perhaps lucky that `If` has attribute `HoldRest`, so that it shows us directly what's going on in your definition of `h`.

I just saw jVincent's comment as I typed this, so I'll just add that you can mix in the `If` statement as follows:

```
h[x_] := (If[x > 2, x /. (y_ /; EvenQ[y] :> True), False]) /; x < 10
```

The condition has to be preceded by a pattern, and here I used `y_` as the named pattern in the innermost rule before applying that rule to `x` using `x /. (y_ ...)`.

Comment: With this definition h[3] returns 3, since it doesn't match the EvenQ[y] pattern. However if I correctly interpreted mikes intentions for the function, it should return unevaluated, since it doesn't match his nested pattern.

Comment: @jVincent I just took the definition of `h` he provided and made it work. It's not the same as `f`, but I didn't think that was the main point.

Comment: Indeed, and your solution shows how to go about using conditional patterns in the return of the function defining pattern. I wanted to point out that the syntax doesn't "elevate" the nested pattern to something which affects the pattern used to match for the function definition.

Answer (score 4):

If you like conditionals and spreading definitions (which I like too), this is how you would do what you wanted (assuming jVincent understood correctly your intentions)

```
h[x_] := haux[x] /; EvenQ[x] /; x < 10
haux[x_] := True /; x > 2
haux[_] := False;
```

The extra symbol can always be localized. Or you can avoid it if you don't mind using other constructs, such as

```
h[x_] := TrueQ[x>2]/; EvenQ[x] /; x < 10
```

This is probably how I would do it myself. But the first example is probably how I would deal with a longer definition, where the advantages of spreading the concerns are bigger

Answer (score 2):

The built in function `Piecewise` is designed to achieve this exact goal:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{True, x > 2 && x < 10 && EvenQ@x}}, x]
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been shown, but not explicitly stated, `And` tests a series of conditions in sequence and short-circuits to `False` if any of them fail.  Therefore your first example `f` could be written:

```
f[x_ /; x < 10 && x > 2 && EvenQ[x]] := True
```

Notice the order of the tests; your code as written tests outside in, so this is equivalent.

I find your second example, `h`, confusing in terms of expected output.  The complications are:

1. when you expect the function to evaluate and when you don't.
2. what you expect `(True) /; EvenQ[1]` or `(True) /; EvenQ[2]` to do.

One interpretation is that you want `h` to evaluate if `x < 10`:

```
ClearAll[h]

h[x_ /; x < 10] := x > 2 && EvenQ[x]

h /@ {5, 6, 15}
```

> ```
> {False, False, True, h[15]}
> ```

Another interpretation is that you do not want `h` to evaluate unless multiple conditions are met *and* you want to base these conditions on code that is evaluated in the body of the function.  In that case you are looking for [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html#123) which I described briefly in the middle of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1852/121).

Comment: Yes, I "do not want h to evaluate unless multiple conditions are met". But I just want to know is it more or less efficient to use this programming construct, or  is the difference negligible?

Comment: @Mike the form with `And` is marginally more efficient.  I still don't understand why you favor the nested `Condition` form; I wish you would explain its purpose.  Also, I don't know what output you *desire* from `h`.  Would you please give the (fake) output you want from `h /@ Range[0, 12]`?