# Opposite of Alternatives

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, design-patterns

I was looking at this question ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88301/is-there-any-way-to-use-head-of-real-and-integer-altogether)) and I tried to find any thing gives the opposite of `Alternatives`. In other  words, some pattern matching function that gives true when expression matches **ALL** patterns. Is there any function for that?

For example:

`x`  has to be `Integer` **AND** `Real`

The other thing is that from Mr.Wizard solution, suppose I want to make a rule in which `x` has to be `Integer` and `Real` and also  `x>10`, how can I define that in external rule or pattern in one shot and use pattern test `?` or pattern `:`  ( for example to do something like this `f[x_?match]` or `f[x:(pattern)]`)

I hope I made the question clear.

Thank you

Comment: In *Mathematica* a number cannot be both `Integer` and `Real`; those are two completely different heads.

Comment: Can you give an example of a situation which you cannot formulate as a single pattern without using such a construct?  I cannot come up with with a non-convoluted one.  `x_Integer /; x > 10` works.

Comment: I guess you have to resort to `MatchQ` and `&&` in the rare cases when this is necessary.  For example, require that a sequence contain *both* `a,a,a` and  `a,a,b`, which may or may not be overlapping.   Then `seq_ /; MatchQ[seq, {___, a,a,a, ___}] && MatchQ[seq, {___, a, a, b, ___}]`.

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: [(6834)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6834/121)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To directly get the opposite of `Alternatives`, you could negate each pattern with `Except` and then negate the `Alternatives`:

```
also[patts__] := Except[Alternatives @@ Except /@ {patts}]

Cases[Range[1, 15, 1/2], _Integer ~also~ _?(# > 10 &)]

(* {11, 12, 13, 14, 15} *)
```

Generally some other approach will be simpler, though, as discussed in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

Usually one does not need what you ask for.  E.g. a pattern for an even integer greater than 10:

```
x_Integer?EvenQ /; x > 10
```

(`_Integer` is not strictly necessary here as only integers will pass `EvenQ` however it should make the pattern a bit more efficient.)

But since it is an interesting quesiton here is one idea:

```
matchAll[expr_, form_] := matchAll[form][expr]
matchAll[form_List][expr_] := (And @@ (MatchQ /@ form))[expr] // Through
```

Now a function that matches each of three specifications:

```
test = matchAll[{_foo, _[__Integer], x_ /; Length[x] == 3}];
```

And its use:

```
test /@ {{1, 2, 3}, foo[1, 1.5, 2], foo[7, 8], foo[4, 5, 6]}
```

> ```
> {False, False, False, True}
> ```

It can of course be turned into a pattern simply with `_?test`.