# MatchQ’ing Except[…] and Except[…]

Tags: pattern-matching

A `PostScriptForm`<sup>[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101954/looking-for-postscriptform-or-forthform-to-print-expressions-as-rpn-code)</sup> for Mathematica must recurse over the likes of `Plus[…]`. Output should be as follows:

- 9+n: either `9 n add` or `n 9 add`
- 9-n: `9 n sub`
- -9+n: `n 9 sub`
- -9-n: `-9 n sub`

So for my purposes first step is to find the first item of a list that is neither `Times[-1, _]` nor `(n_Integer /; n < 0)`. But `Position[(9 + n), (Except[Times[-1, _]] && Except[(n_Integer /; n < 0)]), 1, Heads -> False]` returns a grumble: “Except::named: "Named pattern variables are not allowed in the first argument of Except[n_Integer/;n<0]”.

Please, kind experts of Mathematica.StackExchange.com, how could this most naturally be done?

This problem has raised other issues — likely to be my failure to master Mathematica’s object model.

```
thing = 9 (* Easy peasy *)
MatchQ[thing, (Except[Times[-1, _]])] (* returns True: happiness *) 
MatchQ[thing, (Except[_?Negative])] (* also returns True: happiness *) 
MatchQ[thing, (Except[Times[-1, _]] && Except[_?Negative])] (* returns False in Mathematica 9.0 (January 24, 2013): why? *)
```

Guidance would be most welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You can't use `&&` because that is a logical connective (i.e. it joins logical statements that will evaluate to `True` or `False`), where in `MatchQ`, you are matching patterns, not finding the expressions where the second argument evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Perhaps [this question and answers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88375/opposite-of-alternatives) will be helpful.

Comment: Not an answer, but just wanted to note that that "named patterns" limitation was addressed somewhere in the version 10 releases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine two or more exceptions with `Alternatives` (|)

```
MatchQ[thing, Except[Times[-1, _] | _?Negative]]
```

> True

Comment: I thought of this, too, but then I realized that `Alternatives` is more like `Or` than `And`, because `MatchQ` will return `True` if *any* of the patterns joined by `Alternatives` match the expression, rather than *all*.

Comment: Read it as `Not[this Or that]` which must evaluate to `True` because `9` is positive and `Times` doesn't apply.

Comment: Oh right, because the `Alternatives` is *inside* the `Except`! I didn't notice that. Nevermind!

Comment: Just what was needed: thank you.

I might have been confused because `Position` seems to take either a pattern or a function evaluating to a Boolean. Whatever, problem cured: thank you.