# Pattern intersection

Tags: pattern-matching

Given a list of patterns `{x, y, z}` I want a pattern that matches if and only if each pattern matches.  If instead of getting the intersection of patterns I wanted the union of patterns I could use `Alternatives`.

I managed to write the following.  Is there a better alternative?

```
Except[Alternatives @@ Map[Except, {x, y, z}]]
```

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Thanks for locating that other question, I had not seen it.  I did more tests, and the solution with Except does not work because named patterns are not allowed.  E.g. I tried `MatchQ[Pi+1,Except[Except[a_?NumericQ],b_Plus]]` and got `Except::named: "Named pattern variables are not allowed in the first argument of Except[a_?NumericQ]."`

Comment: Indeed, this is true.

Comment: In my specific use-case (defining a function `f` which defaults to `Hold` and takes special values when several patterns (with named variables) match simultaneously), I can define `f[a_]:=g[a,a]` and `g[a:pattern1, a:pattern2]:=value` which will only match if the argument matches both `pattern1` and `pattern2`, but it looks somewhat ugly (and slow?).

Comment: In Mathematica 10.4.1 under Windows (and Linux) I get no error message for `MatchQ[Pi + 1, Except[Except[a_?NumericQ], b_Plus]]`, but `True`.

Comment: @RolfMertig Interesting. Indeed so, I tested now. Didn't test for my prev. comment, since this didn't work before, and I knew that. The moral is to always test :)

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch To make your request more formal, the task is to construct the logical `And` for patterns using only the pattern-matcher, and not using the evaluator (`Condition`, `PatternTest`, etc.). If we formulate it this way, then I don't see any other option except double - `Except` (pun intended).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: I should probably delete my question: it is also a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88375/39260 which has an answer with double-`Except` by Simon Rochester.  Right now I'm trying to cook up some code that will allow rule-replacement, i.e. such that `x/.AndRuleDelayed[{patt1,patt2},replacement]` is equivalent to `{x,x}/.{patt1,patt2}:>replacement` when both patterns match, and the replacement is allowed to involve named subpatterns from both `patt1` and `patt2`.  Not sure where I should post that code.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch  You could add it as an answer to either of those past discussions.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: FYI, I've posted a separate question (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116302/opposite-of-alternatives-in-a-rule) with a focus on rules rather than patterns because both earlier questioners seem to only care about patterns.