# Pattern constraint for two or more variables

Tags: pattern-matching

Is it possible to have a pattern constraint for a function with two or more variables where the pattern is a relation between the vars being accepted e.g.

```
f[x_,y_]:=...
```

and I want say, x< 10y. I don't think something like

```
f[x_,y_/; x<10y]
```

will work, or other variants of this that I have tried.

Comment: ...or `f[x_, y_] /; x < 10 y := (* stuff *)`

Comment: Ah, I see thanks.

Comment: Okay, go answer your own question if you understood what I was saying...

Comment: Related:  [Placement of `Condition`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/533/121) and [`PatternTest` versus `Condition`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at why your attempt failed.

```
f[x_, y_ /; x < 10 y] := Mod[x, y]
```

Although the FrontEnd syntax highlighter is sometimes wrong it is helpful in this case:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that the `x` on the left-hand side is not colored as a pattern name.  Indeed this is why it does not work as you desire.  Observe the `Trace`:

```
f[5, 10] // Trace
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see that this attempts comparision to a literal `x` rather than the value `5`.  This can be a useful behavior for global conditions, e.g.:

```
x = 70;

f[5, 10] // Trace
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As to *why* this happens: the values of patterns are only substituted on the *right-hand side* of operators such as `=`, `:=`, `:>` and pivotally `/;`.  Therefore we want both patterns `x_` and `y_` on the LHS of `/;` so that they will be substituted in its RHS.

```
ClearAll[f]

f[x_, y_] /; x < 10 y := Mod[x, y]

f[5, 10] // Trace
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the `TreeForm` of the definition in case the parsing is not apparent:

```
TreeForm @ Unevaluated @ Unevaluated[
  f[x_, y_] /; x < 10 y := Mod[x, y]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See these questions for further guidance on testing arguments:

[Placement of Condition /; expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/533/121)

[Using a PatternTest versus a Condition for pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121)

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work just fine:

```
f[x_, y_] := x y /; x < 10 y
```

Yes, this was said in a comment to the question, but I thought there should be a real answer easy for newcomers to find.

Comment: Filtering the pattern match on the left-hand side as in J.M.'s comment is actually more efficient, since the filter is applied earlier.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Yep. In fact J.M.'s is twice as fast