# ConversionRules and style inheritance

Tags: export, notebooks, stylesheet, latex, conversion

Take the LaTeX-Article stylesheet

```
stylesheet = FileNameJoin[{"Article","LaTeX-Article.nb"}];
```

Compare these outputs

```
ExportString[
 Notebook[{Cell["Numbered?", "Section"]}, StyleDefinitions -> stylesheet],
 "TeXFragment"]

(* \section{Numbered?} *)

ExportString[
 Notebook[{Cell["Numbered?", "Section"]}, 
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> stylesheet]]}]],
 "TeXFragment"]

(* \section*{Numbered?} *)
```

Do you all see this difference? What's the reason for it?

Comment: Éramos pocos... Where have you been?

Comment: @belisarius :) around in the end-of-year rush

Comment: Shaná Tová, then for you and all your dearlings

Comment: @belisarius Thanks, Shaná Tová to you too!

Answer (score 5):

## Why inherited conversion rules are not used

In complicated process of exporting, at some stage, `` System`Convert`CommonDump`ConvertNotebook `` function is called.
If you look at its source, you'll see that it extracts style definitions from notebook and from `$FrontEnd`. Then, for style definitions that are strings or `` FrontEnd`FileName `` expressions, it gets explicit notebook expressions using `` System`Convert`CommonDump`GetStyleSheet `` function. Stylesheet notebooks are then passed to `` System`Convert`CommonDump`StyleSheetsToMarkupRules `` function, to extract conversion rules.

`StyleSheetsToMarkupRules` function starts by calling `` System`Convert`CommonDump`ExtractStyleDataCells ``, which extracts cells matching `Cell[StyleData[_String, ___], ___]` pattern and ignores all other cells. That's why inherited stylesheets, i.e. ones present in `Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> ...]]` cells, are not used in conversion.

Starred section command, in your second example, comes from default rules stored in:

```
System`Convert`CommonDump`DefaultMarkupRules[System`Convert`TeXDump`texsave]
```

## How to fix conversion rules inheritance

Unfortunatly I don't know a way of fixing this without changing behavior of builtin function.

If you don't mind a small hack, you can start with function that takes all style inheritance cells, pointing to filenames and put them at the and of stylesheet notebook, with referenced filenames replaced by explicit notebook expressions.

We need to move inherited styles to the end of notebook, so that definitions from inheriting stylesheet will properly override inherited definitions.

```
ClearAll[styleFilenamePatt, styleInheritanceCell, explicitInheritedStylesheets];

styleFilenamePatt = Except["Core.nb", _String | _System`Convert`CommonDump`fnpatt];
styleInheritanceCell = Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> styleFilenamePatt]];

explicitInheritedStylesheets[styleSheets_] := styleSheets //. Notebook[cells_, opts___] :> 
    Notebook[
        Join[
            DeleteCases[cells, styleInheritanceCell, Infinity]
            , 
            Cases[cells,
                Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> filename : styleFilenamePatt]] :>
                    Cell[StyleData[
                        StyleDefinitions -> System`Convert`CommonDump`GetStyleSheet[filename]
                    ]]
                ,
                Infinity
            ]
        ]
        ,
        opts
    ]
```

Inject `explicitInheritedStylesheets` function to `StyleSheetsToMarkupRules` using [Villegas-Gayley](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39711/14303):

```
Module[{inside},
    System`Convert`CommonDump`StyleSheetsToMarkupRules[
        styleSheets_, markupLanguage_, environment_: None
    ] /; ! TrueQ[inside] :=
        Block[{inside = True},
            System`Convert`CommonDump`StyleSheetsToMarkupRules[
                styleSheets // explicitInheritedStylesheets,
                markupLanguage,
                environment
            ]
        ]
]
```

Now conversion rules from inherited stylesheets should work as expected:

```
ExportString[
    Notebook[{Cell["Numbered?", "Section"]}, StyleDefinitions -> stylesheet],
    "TeXFragment"
]
(* \section{Numbered?} *)

ExportString[
    Notebook[
        {Cell["Numbered?", "Section"]},
        StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> stylesheet]]}]
    ],
    "TeXFragment"
]
(* \section{Numbered?} *)
```