# Mathematica unable to solve easy differential equation $y''+y\,y'=0$ with initial conditions $y(0)=1, y'(0)=-1$

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

Trying to solve the following:

```
DSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] y'[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == -1}, y[x], x]
```

leads *Mathematica* to declare that no analytic solution exists `{}` along with the error:

> DSolve::bvfail: For some branches of the general solution, unable to
>   solve the conditions.

Yet, by performing a very simple substitution of $u = y'$ and solving by hand, we arrive at the remarkably simple solution of $y(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{x}{2}\right)$. Indeed, using Maple to compute the solution yields this answer directly. Why is *Mathematica* unable to solve this DE symbolically while Maple can?

Comment: Nevertheless, it is a NKS - a "new kind of solver", that simply takes longer and solves less problems than Maple as @xzxczd has shown in his link below. :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's well known, that `DSolve` is relatively weak - at least as of now. Frequently we need to help it a bit to obtain the desired solution. In your case, we just need to find the general solution first and then solve for the constant:

```
generalsol = DSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] y'[x] == 0}, y, x][[1]]

const = Solve[{y[0] == 1, y'[0] == -1} /. generalsol // TrigToExp, {C[1], C[2]}, 
   Method -> Reduce][[1]]

y[x] /. generalsol /. const // Simplify
Simplify[%, C[3] ∈ Integers]
(* Cot[1/4 (π + 2 x)] *)
```

Comment: Not sure you really mean "common sense" here? :)

Comment: @gwr (Checking the dictionary) Yeah, I mean "common sense" :D . OK, at least it's a common sense among people frequently dealing with differential equation, I think.

Comment: Huh, I would have thought that Mathematica's DSolve should be best in the field. Good thing there's always maple as a fallback.

Comment: @1110101001 You may find this "interesting": http://12000.org/my_notes/kamek/kamke_differential_equations.htm

Comment: @xzczd Wow that confirms what you said. Maple solved 92% while Mathematica got 72%. And maple did them roughly 30x faster. Maybe Wolfram should work on this core before [poking fun at maple](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/compare-mathematica/compare-mathematica-and-maple.html)

Comment: Re English usage: I think the idiom in this case is "common knowledge."

Comment: Re English usage: If it were "common sense", then it would still be just "common sense". Just like there is one common denominator there are not countably many common senses (probably). :)

Answer (score 7):

`DSolve` as of V11, sets the `Method` option of `Solve` to `Restricted`. This probably fixes some things, but it gets in the way here.  We can try the [Villegas-Gayley](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39711/understanding-villegas-gayley) trick to override the setting. This does it for all instances of `Solve` used by `DSolve`, but it's hard to target the instance that is needed.

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Solve},
 Unprotect[Solve];
 Solve[eq_, v_, opts___] /; ! TrueQ[$in] := Block[{$in = True},
   Solve[eq, v, Method -> Automatic, opts]
   ];
 Protect[Solve];
 sol = DSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] y'[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == -1}, y[x], x]
 ]
(*
  {{y[x] -> 
     ConditionalExpression[I Tanh[1/2 (I x + 1/2 I (-π + 8 π C[3]))], C[3] ∈ Integers]}}
*)
```

This can be simplified as @xzczd does, `Simplify[sol, C[3] ∈ Integers]`.

Comment: Just a side note: this doesn't work in _v9_ (the output is still `{}`), modifying `Solve[eq, v, Method -> Automatic, opts]` to `Solve[eq // TrigToExp, v, opts]` works though.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, your fix for V9 will be helpful. Note one still needs to reset `Method` for it to work in V11: `Solve[eq // TrigToExp, v, Method -> Automatic, opts]`.

Answer (score 4):

**Comment**

Maples `dsolve` is able to solve this IVP without any fuss,

```
restart:
ode:=diff(y(x),x$2)+y(x)*diff(y(x),x$1)=0;
ics:=y(0)=1,D(y)(0)=-1;
sol:=dsolve({ode,ics},y(x));
```

[image]

```
plot(rhs(sol),x=0..3);
```

Comment: yeah I noted that in the opening post

Comment: @1110101001 opening post?

Comment: In the body of my question — "...Maple to compute the solution yields this answer directly"

Comment: @1110101001 not a second order ode, you mentioned first order ode which u get after subbing