# How to prevent Mathematica from complete evaluation of special functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, output-formatting, special-functions, expression-manipulation

Recently I tried to check a result of integration which should be a linear combination of the Riemann $\zeta\;$-function at various arguments, the  coefficients of the combination being of primary interest.

Unfortunately *Mathematica* have expanded all occurrences of $\zeta\;$-functions with even integer arguments.

Is there a way to prevent it from doing that?

A sample code:

```
 Integrate[ Log[1-x]^5/x^5, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is even simpler (thanks to @CarlWoll):

```
ClearSystemCache[]; 
Block[{Zeta = Inactive[Zeta]}, 
 Integrate[Log[1 - x]^5/x^5, {x, 0, 1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Original answer:*

Using the [Gayley-Villegas](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39711/understanding-villegas-gayley) trick:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Zeta},
 Unprotect[Zeta];
 Zeta[a_Integer /; a > 1] /; ! TrueQ[$in] := Block[{$in = True},
   Inactive[Zeta][a]
   ];
 Protect[Zeta];
 Integrate[Log[1 - x]^5/x^5, {x, 0, 1}]
 ]
```

Note: The integral is actually computed in terms of limits of an expression involving `PolyLog[n, 1-x]` (for `n = 2,3,4,5`); we could do something similar for `PolyLog` as was done for `Zeta` above.  However `PolyLog` actually evaluates to `Zeta` first, which is why the above works in this case.  I mention it in case `PolyLog` does not evaluate to `Zeta` in a future version.  And it's possible the integral will not be computed in terms of `PolyLog` in the future, too, I suppose.  In any case, I thought some explanation of why the code happens to work in this case would be helpful.  (It will certainly help me a year from now when someone asks why this doesn't work, and I won't remember a thing about it.)

Comment: Simpler is `ClearSystemCache[]; Block[{Zeta = Inactive[Zeta]}, Integrate[Log[1 - x]^5/x^5, {x, 0, 1}]]`. I tried using this `Block` earlier and it didn't work. When I saw your answer, I realized that the cache was interfering.

Comment: @CarlWoll Ditto for me. But I didn't realize the cache was causing the problem, even though [I mentioned it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171047/how-to-prevent-mathematica-from-complete-evaluation-of-special-functions/171106?noredirect=1#comment449719_171054) to the OP.  (Ha-ha).  Thanks.

Comment: After my comment, I read the comments to the OP, and saw that! lol

Comment: @MichaelE2 This is a nice suggestion, however I would like to recognise when it's superior over a simple pattern matching approach. +1.

Comment: @Artes This fiddling with the internals slows down `Integrate`, even worse if we inactivate `PolyLog` in the same way.  Makes me wonder how safe it is.  In fact, I got a wrong answer with one thing I tried (not shown).  On the other hand, pattern matching can be made much harder if there are coefficients in the integrand that obfuscate or destroy the pattern.  But done your way, it is perfectly safe. (+1 to your answer a while ago.)

Answer (score 8):

*Mathematica* is a term rewriting system and there are various ways to suppress automatic evaluation of expressions. The system doesn't evaluate `Zeta` for odd integer arguments (see e.g. `Zeta[Range[2, 20]]`). `Zeta[n]` yields expressions involving `n`-th powers of `Pi`,  thus one of possible ways to achieve the goal would be e.g.

```
Integrate[Log[1 - x]^5/x^5, {x, 0, 1}] /. 
 Times[x_, Pi^n_Integer] :> x Pi^n Inactivate[Zeta[n]]/Zeta[n] //
 TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Another way is to use `HoldForm[Zeta[n]]` instead of `Inactivate[Zeta[n]]` however the latter is more universal and handy. You can use `Activate` (also with appropriate patterns) to evaluate the expression, e.g.

```
Activate[%]
```

> ```
> -((5 Pi^2)/6) - (11 Pi^4)/18 - 30 (Zeta[3] + Zeta[5])
> ```

Nevertheless using such a replacement should be appropriately restricted to avoid possible ambiguities with expressions involving symbolic results in terms of powers of `Pi`.

Comment: For safety, you can restrict the transformation to even powers of $\pi$: `Times[x_, π^n_?EvenQ]`

Comment: @J.M.needshelp. Right, however the OP might explain if expressions like e.g. `Integrate[BesselK[0, x]^2, {x, 0, Infinity}]` are subject to transform or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However we are just lucky that in this special case we can recognize our function by a power of $\pi $. It may be however a more general function with a "simple" value at a special point. Is there a general way to prevent *Mathematica*  from evaluation of some listed functions?

Comment: @drer I've mentioned about pattern option in `Inactivate` which could  be exploited.  With an example at hand this could be worked out, nonetheless there is no obvious general way.

Comment: A simple example would be an output of a calculation equivalent to `Range[1,20]Sin[Pi/Range[1,20]]`. It is really hard to find a method of "postprocessing". It would be better somehow tell *Mathematica* never evaluate `Sin`. But as I understood it is impossible.

Comment: @drer Re "in this special case we can recognize our function by a power of π": It's not clear that it is because `Zeta` is evaluating that we have powers of π in the answer.  Executing `Block[{Zeta = Inactive[Zeta]}, Integrate[Log[1 - x]^5/x^5, {x, 0, 1}]]` suggests that the powers of π are computed without using `Zeta`. If so, one cannot blame the evaluation of special functions for returning a correct answer in a certain form.

Comment: @MichaelE2 In Wolfram Cloud your code resulted in `-5 (Zeta[2]+6Zeta[3]+11Zeta[4]+6Zeta[5])` as it was desired. Thank you!!!

Comment: @MichaelE2 A next try after some pause with the same command has however resulted in expansion of "even" `Zeta`. I have really no clue what is happening here.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It is certainly a bug in Wolfram Cloud. If I execute once the command `Integrate[Log[1 - x]^n/x^n, {x, 0, 1}]]` with some `n` either inside or outside of the `Block[{Zeta=Inactive[Zeta]},...]`, **all** subsequent calls **with the same** `n` result in the same output as in the first one, completely independent from the art of the call (inside or outside of the `Block`). It however does not influence subsequent calls of the command **with a different not yet used** `n`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Please consider posting an answer with your suggestion, pointing out also the bug (obviously present in your version of *Mathematica* as well).

Comment: @drer Well, I'm not sure I understand yet. The integral is calculated as the `Limit` of an expression in terms of `PolyLog`, `Log` and powers of `x`, not in terms of `Zeta`.  It's the polylogs that evaluate to zeta inside the limit call. Another possible issue is that replacement rules can be used to rewrite expressions, not just evaluation. -- As for reproducibility, note that sometimes expressions are cached and reused, rather than recalculated.  `ClearSystemCache` can sometimes be used to reset the cache.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Were you able to reproduce the "correct" result?