# How to override a built-in Mathematica function using its old version?

Tags: function-construction, customization, built-in-symbols

How can we override a Mathematica built-in function using itself in the definition?

For example, the `DiracDelta` function is not defined for complex numbers like:

```
In[1]:= N[DiracDelta[1 + 2 I]]

Out[1]= DiracDelta[1. + 2. I]
```

But how can we change its behavior for something similar to this?

```
Unprotect[DiracDelta];
DiracDelta[x_] := DiracDelta[Re[x] + Im[x]];
Protect[DiractDelta];
```

With this approach we receive an **infinite recursion** error.

We could define another function, like DiractDelta2[x_] with the expected behavior, but the problem is more because I'd needing to see some simplifications when I'm expanding my series, and for those cases it is ok to define it that way.

**Attempts**

```
OldDiracDelta = DiracDelta;
Unprotect[DiracDelta];
DiracDelta[x_] := OldDiracDelta[Re[x] + Im[x]];
Protect[DiractDelta];
(* But unfortunately this still incurs in the infinite recursion error. *)
```

Comment: Could restrict the definition as: `DiracDelta[Complex[x_,y_]]:=DiracDelta[x +y]` (not commenting on the sensibility of such a definition).

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39711/12 In this case you don't need such a heavyweight approach, just more specific patterns, as pointed out by Daniel

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanielLichtblau, it works! =)
DanielLichtblau, would you like to post it as an answer? I'd like to accept it.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I wasn't able to really understand the solution of your link, but I'll try to keep this in mind ;)

Comment: I've seen that this approach `DiracDelta[Complex[x_,y_]]:=DiracDelta[x +y]` do not always work as expected. If you have something like `DiractDelta[I]` it doesn't resolve. If you extend more, like adding `DiractDelta[I*x_] := DiracDelta[x]` it works but I've seen a lot of other cases appearing, unfortunately. Maybe I need to try something using ComplexExpand first.