# Function with condition

Tags: functions

I am starting my adventure with Mathematica.
I would like to know if is there possibility to create function described by formula for example  f(x):=1+2^n where 2^n < x. I have problem with this condition. I tried something like f[x_]:=(1+2^n) && (2^n< x) but probably it's wrong way.
I'll be gratefull for any help

Edit:

Ok, let's take the function described by f(x)=1+2^n where n is solution of inequality 2^(-n) <= |x-1| < 2^(1-n) (n is integer) and we can define f(1)=1.

so for example f(3)=1+2^(-1) because n=-1 is solution of 2^(-n) <= |3-1| < 2^(1-n).

I'd like to create a plot of this or similar function. I tried something like:
f[x_]:= 1 + 2^(n) /; n = Reduce[{2^(-n) <= Abs[ x - 1] < 2^(1 - n)}, k, Integers] but without success. I don't know how correctly put n value.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I think that you should be to see [Condition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html)

Answer (score 7):

The question of what you want to happen when the condition is not met will determine how you should proceed.  If you wish the function to remain unevaluated try [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html):

```
f[x_] := (1 + 2^n) /; 2^n < x

n = 7;

f[100]
f[200]
```

> ```
> f[100]
>
> 129
> ```

See:

- [Placement of Condition /; expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/533/placement-of-condition-expressions?s=1|2.2541)
- [Using a PatternTest versus a Condition for pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121)

For plotting or mathematical operations consider [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) or [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html):

```
Plot[
 ConditionalExpression[1 + 2^n, 2^n < x],
 {x, 0, 200},
 Frame -> True
]
```

[image]

```
Plot[
 Piecewise[{{1 + 2^n, 2^n < x}}],
 {x, 0, 200},
 Frame -> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's very useful. But I'd like to dynamically compute n value. I tried something like for example:
f[x_] = 1 + 2^(n) /; n = 
  Reduce[{2^(-n) <= Abs[ x - 1] < 2^(1 - n)}, k, Integers] But doesn't work correctly

Comment: @adolzi Please add to the question examples of the actual input and output that you expect from your function.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this:

```
f[x_] := 1 + 2^IntegerPart[x];
```

looking as

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "f"}]
```

[image]

??

Comment: Not exactly, but thank you, it's clever :) but I will change conditions flexible. For example I am going  to create a plot of function described by formule f(x)=1+2^n where 2^n <= |x| < 2^(1-n) where n is Integer and extra f(0)=1