# Question about Rules and Pattern (The operator patt/;test)

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, operators, conditional

Maybe this question is so trivial but it has confused me.
I'm studying the [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/30689) and in the `Rules and patterns` under the [Reference for the operator /;](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) there is this example:

```
In[1]:= f[x_] := ppp[x] /; x > 0 
In[2]:= f[5]
Out[2]= ppp[5]
In[3]:= f[-6]
Out[3]= f[-6]
```

Based on the above example I thought the answer of the following code should be **f[-2]**, as the following:

```
In[1]:= f[x_] = Sqrt[x] /; x > 0
Out[1]= Sqrt[x] /; x > 0
In[2]:= f[2]
Out[2]= Sqrt[2] /; 2 > 0
In[3]:= f[-2]
Out[3]= f[-2]
```

I mean the definition `f[x_] = Sqrt[x]` should only be used when `x>0`. So when I enter `-2` as the argument, the definition should not be used and the output will be `f[-2]`. But in fact mathematica evaluates the code as follows:

```
In[1]:= f[x_] = Sqrt[x] /; x > 0
Out[1]= Sqrt[x] /; x > 0
In[2]:= f[2]
Out[2]= Sqrt[2] /; 2 > 0
In[3]:= f[-2]
Out[3]= i Sqrt[2] /; -2 > 0
```

In spite of the fact that `-2<0`, *Mathematica* uses the definition and produces the answer $i\sqrt{2}$
What's the difference between this code and the first one that makes mathematica use the definition in spite of the negative argument passed to the function?

---

*Update: Response to closure (Michael E2)*

There must be something quite subtle going on.  It is not just the usual explanation that `Set` evaluates the right-hand and `SetDelayed` does not, because the right-hand side evaluates to itself (assuming, as [Mr. Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) answer points out, that `x` has no value).  This can be seen because the down values are the same in each case:

```
f1[x_] := Sqrt[x] /; x > 0;
f2[x_] = Sqrt[x] /; x > 0;

DownValues@f1
DownValues@f2

(* {HoldPattern[f1[x_]] :> Sqrt[x] /; x > 0} *)
(* {HoldPattern[f2[x_]] :> Sqrt[x] /; x > 0} *)
```

Comment: Related: [(8829)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8829/121)

Comment: I disagree with the close votes.  This is a subtle error not explained at all in the documentation, AFAICS.  There are valid reasons for using `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` as well as reasons for putting constraints on patterns.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard not just related, but already covered and answered there, I think.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When using [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) rather than [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) you will need to hang the [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) on the left-hand-side:

```
ClearAll[f]

f[x_] /; x > 0 = Sqrt[x]
f[2]
f[-2]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[x]
>
> Sqrt[2]
>
> f[-2]
> ```

There are other reasons to prefer this placement; see:

- [Placement of Condition /; expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/533/121)

However be aware that the use of `Set` results in "pre-evaluation" of the RHS which often is not desirable.  For example suppose the global Symbol `x` has a value before the definition is made:

```
ClearAll[f]
x = 7;

f[x_] /; x > 0 = Sqrt[x]
f[2]
f[-2]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[7]
>
> Sqrt[7]
>
> f[-2]
> ```

This is probably not what you want.  Using `:=` works:

```
ClearAll[f]

x = 7;

f[x_] /; x > 0 := Sqrt[x]
f[2]
f[-2]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[2]
>
> f[-2]
> ```