# Pollard's Rho algorithm

Tags: function-construction, algorithm, number-theory, cryptography

I'm working in Mathematica and I'm trying to implement the [Pollard's Rho Algorithm for the Discrete Logartihm Problem][1].

Answer (score 5):

Try using the Which function:

```
f[0] = 1;
f[x_] := 
  Which[
    Mod[x, 3] == 1, h*f[x-1], 
    Mod[x, 3] == 2, f[x-1]^2, 
    Mod[x, 3] == 0, g*f[x-1] ]
```

This will take input x and return the first condition which evaluates true

Answer (score 3):

You can chain `If`s together:  `If[(condition1), (something), If[(condition2), (something else), If[(condition3), (another thing), (otherwise)]]]` or use `Which` or `Switch` but I think you're better off using conditioned patterns (patterns that use `/;`).  For example,

```
With[{h=foo,g=baz},(* <-- since I don't know the actual values *)
 PollardX[0]=1;
 PollardX[i_]:=h PollardX[i-1]/;Mod[i,3]==1;
 PollardX[i_]:=  PollardX[i-1]^2/;Mod[i,3]==2;
 PollardX[i_]:=g PollardX[i-1]/;Mod[i,3]==0;
 ]
```

And now

```
PollardX/@Range[8]
(* yields {foo,foo^2,baz foo^2,baz foo^3,baz^2 foo^6,baz^3 foo^6,baz^3 foo^7,baz^6 foo^14}*)
```

Comment: An interesting post about the placement of `Condition (/;)`: [533](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/533/57).

Comment: That's a good discussion!  I usually read `/; test` as "...only if `test`", which nicely (in my mind) goes at the end of sentences.